# How can I change a function depending on what is happening on a view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In my SwiftUI project, I have a bar graph that shows the user's steps over the past 7 days (using HealthKit). This is done by a simple function (fetchWeeklyStepData).

This data is displayed in a bar graph I made called WeeklyBarGraph().

I want to make it so that when the user swipes right or taps a back button on the graph, the week before data is shown, and when tapped again, the week before that step data will be shown.

How would I alter my code in order to implement this functionality? Would I use TabViews and Indexes, and how can I modify my function to make this functionality possible?

Here is my code:

```
struct WeeklyStepsStats: View {

    @State private var stepData: [StepData] = []

    var body: some View {
    
        VStack {
        
        if stepData.isEmpty {
            
            Text("No health data availale")

            
        } else {
            
            VStack {

                WeeklyBarGraph(stepData: stepData)

            }
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .fill(Color.white)
            )
        }
    }
        .onAppear {
                   
            fetchWeeklyStepData()
        }
    }
        
    func fetchWeeklyStepData() {
        guard let stepCountType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount) else {
            return
        }

        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let startOfDay = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())

        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.day = -7

        guard let startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: startOfDay) else {
            return
        }

        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: startOfDay, options: .strictStartDate)

        let query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: stepCountType,
                                                quantitySamplePredicate: predicate,
                                                options: .cumulativeSum,
                                                anchorDate: startDate,
                                                intervalComponents: DateComponents(day: 1))

        query.initialResultsHandler = { query, results, error in
            guard let results = results else {
                return
            }

            var newData: [StepData] = []

            results.enumerateStatistics(from: startDate, to: startOfDay) { statistics, _ in
                if let sumQuantity = statistics.sumQuantity() {
                    let date = statistics.startDate
                    let stepCount = sumQuantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count())

                    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
                    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

                    let data = StepData(id: UUID().uuidString, numberOfSteps: stepCount, date: date)
                    newData.append(data)
                }
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                stepData = newData
            }
        }

        HKHealthStore().execute(query)
    }
}
```

```
struct WeeklyBarGraph: View {
    var stepData: [StepData]
    @GestureState var isDragging: Bool = false
    @State var offset: CGFloat = 0
    @State var currentDataID: String = ""
    @State var isTapped: Bool = false
    @State var showAverageText: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
           
            VStack {
                
                Text("Weekly Summary")
                
                Text(getDateRangeText())
            }
            
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(stepData) { data in
                        CardView(data: data)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.currentDataID = data.id
                                self.showAverageText = false
                            }
                    }
                }
                .animation(.easeOut, value: isDragging)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .updating($isDragging) { value, state, _ in
                            state = true
                        }
                        .onChanged { value in
                            offset = isDragging ? value.location.x : 0
                            let draggingSpace = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 60
                            let eachBlock = draggingSpace / CGFloat(stepData.count)
                            let temp = Int(offset / eachBlock)
                            let index = max(min(temp, stepData.count - 1), 0)
                            self.currentDataID = stepData[index].id
                            self.showAverageText = false
                        }
                        .onEnded { value in
                            withAnimation {
                                offset = .zero
                                currentDataID = ""
                                self.showAverageText = true
                            }
                        }
                )
                
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .overlay(
                        VStack {
                            if showAverageText {

                                    VStack {
                                        Text("Average")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .font(.system(size: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.065))
                                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                        
                                        Text("\(getAverageStepsPerDay())")
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .font(.system(size: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.065))
                                    }
                                         
                            } else {
                                if let selectedData = stepData.first(where: { $0.id == currentDataID }) {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text(getFormattedDate(selectedData.date))
                                                                                
                                        Text("\(Int(selectedData.numberOfSteps))")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    )
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getXPosition() -> CGFloat {
        let index = stepData.firstIndex { $0.id == currentDataID } ?? 0
        let barWidth: CGFloat = 30
        let spacing: CGFloat = 10
        let initialOffset: CGFloat = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - CGFloat(stepData.count) * (barWidth + spacing) + spacing) / 2
        return initialOffset + CGFloat(index) * (barWidth + spacing) + barWidth / 2
    }
    
    func getAverageStepsPerDay() -> Int {
        let totalSteps = stepData.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.numberOfSteps }
        let averageSteps = Double(totalSteps) / Double(stepData.count)
        return Int(averageSteps)
    }
    
    func getFormattedDate(_ date: Date) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, d"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
    
    func getDateRangeText() -> String {
        guard let startDate = stepData.first?.date,
              let endDate = stepData.last?.date else {
            return ""
        }
        
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d"
        
        let startDateText = dateFormatter.string(from: startDate)
        let endDateText = dateFormatter.string(from: endDate)
        
        return "\(startDateText) - \(endDateText)"
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func CardView(data: StepData) -> some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                let size = proxy.size
                
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                    .fill(.blue)
                    .opacity(isDragging || isTapped ? (currentDataID == data.id ? 1 : 0.35) : 1)
                    .frame(height: (data.numberOfSteps / getMaxNumberOfSteps()) * (size.height))
                    .overlay(
                        Text("")
                            .opacity(isDragging && currentDataID == data.id ? 1 : 0)
                            .opacity(isTapped && currentDataID == data.id ? 1 : 0)
                            .offset(y: -30),
                        alignment: .top
                    )
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
            }
            
            Text(data.date.dayOfWeekLetter())
                .font(.callout)
                .foregroundColor((isDragging || isTapped) && currentDataID == data.id ? .blue : .gray)
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            if currentDataID == data.id {
                isTapped.toggle()
            } else {
                isTapped = true
            }
            self.currentDataID = data.id
            
            if isTapped {
                self.currentDataID = data.id
                self.showAverageText = false
            } else {
                currentDataID = ""
                self.showAverageText = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getMaxNumberOfSteps() -> Double {
        let max = stepData.max { first, second in
            return second.numberOfSteps > first.numberOfSteps
        }
        
        return max?.numberOfSteps ?? 0
    }
}
```

```
struct StepData: Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let numberOfSteps: Double
    let date: Date
}
```

I want to make it so that when the user swipes left and right, the weeks change and the data is fetched from that week.

Comment: Read about arguments and call the function every time you have a new argument

Comment: @loremipsum The function would need to change though (it currently does past 7 days) and how do you call a function when an argument changes? Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: OnChange, task with id, onReceive, etc.